# how to Upload a new apk while the other apk is under review in play store?

Tags: android, google-play

Actually I published my android app in play store and it is under review. But now I changed some of my code and need to upload it in to the play store. My question is, Should I change the version name in the manifest file and export it or can i export it with the previous version name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload an application with the same version name as long as you increment the version code.